# Django:get_queryset() is not popping up filter() method

Tags: python, django

I wrote a custom model manager in my Django project and below the code is

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.utils import timezone
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    # Create your models here.
    
    
        class PublishedManager(models.Manager):
    
            def get_queryset(self):
            return super(PublishedManager,self).get_queryset().filter(status='published')
    
    
    class Post(models.Model):
    
        STATUS_CHOICES = (
            ('draft', 'DRAFT'),
            ('published', 'Published'),
        )
    
        title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
        slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='publish')
        author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blog_posts')
        body = models.TextField()
        publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
        created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='draft')
        objects = models.Manager()
        published = PublishedManager()
    
        class Meta:
            ordering = ('-publish',)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.title
```

While executing `Post.published.filter(title__startswith='Who')` in command shell I am getting below error `AttributeError: 'PublishedManager' object has no attribute 'filter'`.

Comment: Can you print the full (or relevant parts of the) traceback?

Comment: Furthermore it is probably worth to fix the indentation, since right now, we can not repreoduce it. Are you sure you did not forget the brackets in `published = PublishedManager()`?

Comment: Thanks Willem for the response. I am not sure, today morning it is working fine.  I haven't made any change.     >>> from blog.models import Post
>>> Post.published.filter(title__startswith='Who')
<QuerySet []>
>>> Post.published.filter(title__startswith='Ca')
<QuerySet [<Post: Canada Immigration is easy??>]>
>>>

Comment: Do you, by any change use subversioning, such that you can see what changes you made?

Answer (score 0):

```
class CustomManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(status="published")
```

Comment: Please provide informative description about your answer to give better understanding of the solution.